# Restsharp returns error 404 but link is working in a web browser

Tags: c#, http, post, request, restsharp

I'm trying to send some data to web api but I get error 404: Not found. I tried link in a web browser and it's working fine. I'm using restsharp to post request. Here's my code:

```
        var restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(resource);
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        restClient.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        restClient.UserAgent = "Windows Phone";
        restClient.FollowRedirects = false;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(new ScoreInputModel{ username = uname, email = mail, password = pass, gender = "Male" });            
        try
        {
            restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(response.Content.ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }

            });
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you control the server side? Have you tried emulating the same User-Agent as the browser?

Comment: No, that is not my server so I don't have any control over it. I tried that doesn't work.

Comment: There's not enough data to say what could be going wrong. My advice would be to compare the HTTP requests generated by your app and browser side by side, and/or add them to your post.

Comment: I did that, thank you, actually method was not post but get. In official documentation it said that it is POST but looks like they update it without changing documentation. Thank you once again.

Comment: No problem, so presumably changing your method to GET resolved the issue?

Comment: Yes, method was not at all POST. I used fiddler to inspect it. Values should be sent as url segments. Here is my updated request:

            var request = new RestRequest("/resource?{id}&{id}&{id}&{id}&{id}&{id}&{id}", Method.GET); where id is parameter.